# unicorn and nginx, went wrong

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, unicorn, capistrano

I try to deploy my app via capistrano. It was done, but when I start to nginx and show my site in the browser I see '**We're sorry, but something went wrong.**'

It is bad. I use unicorn. See my configs https://gist.github.com/3904032
I try to start server via `rails s -e prodiction` and it's work!

I think that this error may be because I can't restart server

```
root@li272-194:~# /etc/init.d/nginx restart
Restarting nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: still could not bind()
nginx.
```

any ideas?

nginx log

```
2012/10/17 02:57:41 [error] 3271#0: *1 could not find named location "@myapp", client: 91.192.62.77, server: 178.79.153.194, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "178.79.153.194"

2012/10/17 02:19:08 [crit] 2448#0: *8 connect() to unix:/srv/zarcon/shared/unicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.192.62.77, server: zarkon, request:
"GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/srv/zarcon/shared/unicorn.sock:/", host: "178.79.153.194"
```

Comment: Something is already binding to a port that nginx tries to bind to.

Comment: yes, but who is?

Comment: Use e.g. `lsof -i -U` or `netstat -ntlp` and check if there is something listening to `0.0.0.0:80` already.

Comment: done https://gist.github.com/3904092

Comment: Are you sure that nginx stops before it gets started again? Can you try to run `/etc/init.d/nginx stop` and then verify that the process is gone and nothing is listening on :80 before you start up nginx again?

Comment: Also, check your nginx errorlog for any relevant messages.

Comment: errorlog up, where nginx see @myapp?

Comment: line 32 in the nginx configuration. Did you mean to write: `try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @zarkon;` ?

Comment: thank you, error was in nginx config where `pid /tmp/nginx.pid; ` and line 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 32 in your nginx configuration refer to `@myapp`

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @myapp;
```

Did you mean to refer to `@zarkon`?

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @zarkon;
```

and commit `pid /tmp/nginx.pid;` string